# Why my object is not showing in Rendered result but in the Rendered viewpart?

Tags: rendering

[image]

Im facing this problem for the first time and it looks very funny to me because there is no issue with the settings.

My object is showing in the Rendered viewpart but when i hit render for final image result its nothing in the result. lol

Answer (score 0):

O my goodness.
This was the problem i find out myself. [image]